# Google Classroom API list Materials

Tags: google-api, google-classroom

Exists any way to list Materials in the Google Classroom Reports? I get the announcements and coursework, but materials not appears:

[image]

[image]

I'm using:

```
<?php
    $client    = $this->google->getClient();
    $service   = new Google_Service_Classroom($client);
    $optParams = array(
                    'courseStates'  => 'ACTIVE',
                    'pageSize'      => 20,
                    'teacherId'     => $teacher,
    );
    $results = $service->courses->listCourses($optParams);

    foreach($results->getCourses() as $r)
    {
      $course = (string)$r->getId();
      // coursework
      $work = $service->courses_courseWork->listCoursesCourseWork($course, array());
      // ...

      // announcements
      $announ = $service->courses_announcements->listCoursesAnnouncements($course, array('announcementStates'  => 'PUBLISHED'));
     // ...
    }

    // materials???
```

**Edited 31/01/19**:

I've tested the suggestion of @Mr.Rebot. The problem is Classroom API list only files o drive files attached in assigments... materials like this:

[image]

My problem is that I need to list the new Classroom option of materials:

[image]

[image]

So, when I query the ->getMaterials() of the coursework, I get an empty array()

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the scope which is

```
Google_Service_Classroom::CLASSROOM_COURSEWORKMATERIALS
Google_Service_Classroom::CLASSROOM_COURSEWORKMATERIALS_READONLY
```

then you can retrieve the list by calling

```
$this->service->courses_courseWorkMaterials->listCoursesCourseWorkMaterials($course_id);
```

Answer (score -3):

If you'll check the `courses.courseWork` [overview](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork), you'll see that `materials[]` is included there.

```
{
  "courseId": string,
  "id": string,
  "title": string,
  "description": string,
  "materials": [
    {
      object(Material)
    }
  ],

.......
```

Just get materials under `courseWork` response.